# How to Debug Missing[NotAvailable] error for Social Media Data

Tags: debugging, data-acquisition, social-media

I get a `Missing[NotAvailable]` error message when trying to access Social Media Data using `SocialMediaData["Facebook", "Friends"]` in *Mathematica 9* on Linux. Now, I don't know how to find the source of the error. I don't have the same error for twitter. Is there a way to get verbose error information?

Comment: Is this the trial version? If that's the case the problem lies in restrictions placed on `ExportString` in this version. Only thing you can do is obtaining a student/home-use/full license.

Comment: It's a full Mathematica for sites license.

Comment: I also have a full Mathematica license and I get the same error message. I wonder if it has something to do with privacy settings in Facebook.

Comment: What about other properties like SocialMediaData["Facebook","UserData"]? If other also gave you the same Missing error, then it might be your access code is incorrectly copied.

Comment: I have tried some properties which did not work, but I originally did not try the "UserData" property. It is indeed working for me, while Properties like "Friends" or "FriendIDs" are still not working.

Comment: A quick check of Mathematica 9.0.1 seems to show that the problems with SocialMediaData (at least for Facebook) have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with sites license, here is the permission setting on Facebook.

[image: Facebook setting]

Comment: My privacy settings look pretty much the same.